# Space between the posts in the first column of my Tumblr Blog

Tags: css

I'm having an issue with my Tumblr blog, when it loads the posts on my page it loads them all fine but in the first column of posts it has a large gap between some of the posts (e.g. https://i.gyazo.com/55aa87d00504874d6900c1dbc493183d.png).

I'm unsure as to what the issue is as I've looked through the HTML and I can't seem to fathom out what the issue is. Any help would be greatly appreciated it.

Please find my code here:

```html
<!----------

darling theme // divisionthemes
   
---------->

<head>
<meta name="color:background" content="#ffffff"/>
<meta name="color:text" content="#000000"/>
<meta name="color:post titles" content="#585858"/>
<meta name="color:link" content="#1c1c1c"/>
<meta name="color:hover" content="#ffffff"/>
<meta name="color:description text" content="#000000"/>
 
<meta name="image:sidebar" content=""/>
<meta name="image:background" content=""/>

<meta name="if:show sidebar pic" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:three columns" content="0"/>

<meta name="text:Link One Title" content="home"/>
<meta name="text:Link One" content="/"/>
<meta name="text:Link Two Title" content="self"/>
<meta name="text:Link Two" content="/"/>
<meta name="text:Link Three Title" content="him"/>
<meta name="text:Link Three" content="/"/>
<meta name="text:Link Four Title" content="etc"/>
<meta name="text:Link Four" content="/"/>
<meta name="text:Link Four Title" content="etc"/>
<meta name="text:Link Four" content="/"/>
 
<title>{Title}</title>

{block:Description}
<meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}"/>{/block:Description}
 
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/7qjmkr5/IUmmdsy41/jquery.style-my-tooltips.js"></script>
<script>
(function($){$(document)
.ready(function(){$("[title]")
.style_my_tooltips();});})
(jQuery);
</script>

<style type="text/css">

@font-face {font-family:customfont; src: url('http://static.tumblr.com/ejm8w78/E7bmdzk1u/kgthefighter.ttf');,}

#s-m-t-tooltip {  
height:auto;
padding: 3px; 
margin-top:11px;
margin-left: 14px;
font-family: consolas;
font-size: 10px;
text-transform:lowercase;
text-align: center;
letter-spacing:1px;
line-height: 8px;
border: 1px solid #777;
border-radius:5px;
background:#ffffff;
color: #888;
z-index: 999999999999;
}
 
iframe#tumblr_controls {
position: fixed !important;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.7s linear;
opacity: 0.09;
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
-webkit-filter:invert(100%);}
 
iframe#tumblr_controls:hover{
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.7s linear;
opacity: 0.8;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
transition: all 0.4s ease-out;}

body {
margin:0px;
background-color: {color:Background};
background-image:url({image:Background});
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: repeat;
}

{block:iftinycursor}
body, a, a:hover {cursor: url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/cursors/cur-9/cur817.cur), progress;}
{/block:iftinycursor}
 
body, div, p, parea, submit, input{
font-family:consolas;
font-size: 10px;
line-height: 9px;
letter-spacing:0px;
color:{color:Text};
}
 
txt {
margin:0px;
margin-top:5px;
}
 
a:link, a:active, a:visited{
color: {color:Link};
text-decoration: none;
transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-o-transition-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
a:hover {
color: {color:hover};
text-decoration: none;
letter-spacing: 0px;
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-o-transition-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
{block:iftinycursor}
cursor: url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/cursors/cur-9/cur817.cur);
{/block:iftinycursor}
}
 
#center {
margin:auto;
position:relative;
width: 1500px;
overflow:auto;
overflow-y:hidden;
}
 
#content {
width:650px;
{block:ifthreecolumns}
width:850px;
{/block:ifthreecolumns}
max-width:100%;
margin-left: 350px;
{block:iftinycursor}
cursor: url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/cursors/cur-9/cur817.cur);
{/block:iftinycursor}
}
 
#entry {
{block:IndexPage}width: 250px;{/block:indexpage}
{block:PermalinkPage}width: 400px;{/block:PermalinkPage}
background: white;
opacity:1;
margin-top:0px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-right:0px;
margin-bottom:-10px;
padding:10px;
float:left;
display:block;
text-align:justify;
line-height: 5px;
border: 1px solid white;
-webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
-moz-transition: all .3s linear;
transition: all .3s linear;
opacity:.99;
{block:ifpaleposts}
opacity:.6;
{/block:ifpaleposts}
}
 
#entry img {
{block:IndexPage}max-width: 250px;border-radius:5px;{/block:indexpage}
{block:PermalinkPage}max-width: 399px; padding-right: 1px;{/block:PermalinkPage}
}

#blogtitle {
font-family:customfont;
font-size:18px;
color:{color:text};
letter-spacing:1px;
padding-bottom:0px;
padding-top:1px;
margin-bottom:5px;
line-height:20px;
font-style:normal;
text-transform:lowercase;
text-align:center;
opacity:1;
}
 
#sidebar {
position:fixed;
width:190px;
height:auto;
background-color:white;
margin-top:180px;
margin-left:100px;
padding:6px;
color: {color:description text};
border-radius:5px;
opacity:.8;
}

#desclinks {
width:190px;
height:auto;
background-color:white;
margin-left:0px;
border-radius:5px;
padding-bottom:3px;
}

.permz{
width:255;
display: block;
padding: 1px;
margin: 4px 8px 1px 8px;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-family: "consolas";
font-size: 9px;
color: #424242;
line-height: 8px;
text-align: right;
border-radius:6px;
text-decoration: none;
-webkit-transition: color 0.5s ease-out;
-moz-transition: color 0.5s ease-out;
border-top: 1px solid #a5a3a3;
}
 
#entry .perms{
position:absolute;
height:12px;
overflow:hidden;
top: 15px;
left: 20px;
opacity:0;
background-color:#fff;
width:auto;
border-radius:5px;
-webkit-transition: all .5s linear;
-moz-transition: all .5s linear;
transition: all .5s linear;
padding:10px;
padding-top:10px;
}
 
#entry:hover .perms{
margin-top: 6px;
width:auto;
opacity:0.99;
-webkit-transition: all .5s linear;
-moz-transition: all .5s linear;
transition: all .5s linear;
}
 
#entry .perms .permstext{
text-transform:uppercase;
font-family:"consolas";
font-size:10px;
line-height: 10px;
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
opacity:0.99;
background-color:#fff;
-webkit-transition: all .4s linear;
-moz-transition: all .4s linear;
transition: all .4s linear;
}
 
#titletext{
font-family: consolas;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size: 12px;
color: {color:post titles};
font-weight: none;
line-height:11px;
}

#titletext .bodytext{
font-family: consolas;
text-transform:lowercase;
font-size: 10px;
color: {color:text};
font-weight: none;
line-height:10px;
}
 
.video embed, .post div.video object {
{block:IndexPage}
width:250px !important;
{/block:indexpage}
{block:PermalinkPage}
width:400px !important;
{/block:PermalinkPage}
}
 
.chat .lux{
background-color:#ffffff;
margin: 0 0 1px;
padding: 2px;
}

.chat .lux.box{
background-color:#F0F0F0;
}
 
#askr {
font-family:consolas;
font-size:10px;
text-transform:uppercase;
}

#qstn {
background-color:white;
border: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
text-align:center;
margin-bottom:0px;
padding:10px;
}
 
#audio {
width: 220px;
height:auto;
min-height:60px;
padding-bottom:0px;
}

.audiotext{
position:relative;
background:transparent;
border:1px solid #eee;
padding:8px;
font-family:consolas;
font-size:8px;
overflow-x:auto;
letter-spacing:1px;
font-style:italic;
text-transform:uppercase;
height:64px;
margin-top:-20px;
margin-bottom:20px;
margin-left:85px;
padding-left:5px;
line-height:10px;
}

.aplayer{
position:absolute;
border:1px solid #ffffff;
background: #fff;
padding:2px;
padding-top:5px;
margin-left:24px;
margin-top:5px;
width:29px;
height:29px;
opacity:0.89;
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}


.aart{
margin-left:0px;
margin-bottom:20px;
}

.aart img{
background:#fff;
width:60px;
float:left;
padding:10px;
border:1px solid #f0f0f0;
}

</style>

{block:indexpage}
{block:NextPage}<div id="page-nav"><a href="{NextPage}"></a></div>{/block:NextPage}
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
 
<script src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/desandro/masonry/master/masonry.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/jnmer2r/WKhljk73d/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>

<script>

jQuery(window).load(function(){
var $wall = $('#content');
$wall.imagesLoaded(function(){$wall.masonry({
singleMode: true,columnWidth: 261,
itemSelector: '#entry'});});
$wall.infinitescroll({navSelector : '#page-nav',nextSelector : '#page-nav a',itemSelector : '#entry',},
 function( newElements ){$(newElements).hide();setTimeout(function(){
$wall.masonry({ appendedContent: $(newElements) });},2000);
setTimeout(function(){$(newElements).fadeIn('slow');},2100);},1000);});

</script>


<script>

$.fn.imagesLoaded = function(callback){var elems = this.find('img'),
len = elems.length,_this = this;if ( !elems.length ) {
callback.call( this );} elems.bind('load',function(){if (--len <= 0)
{callback.call( _this );}}).each(function(){
if (this.complete || this.complete === undefined){var src = this.src;
this.src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==";this.src = src;}});return this;};

</script>
 
{/block:Indexpage}
 
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="{RSS}" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=820" />
</head>
<style type="text/css">
a.btn{position:absolute;z-index:999999999999;white-space:nowrap;outline:0;text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer;overflow:hidden;font:600 12px/18px "Helvetica Neue","HelveticaNeue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;height:20px;padding:0 5px;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-ms-box-sizing:border-box;-o-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-transition-property:padding;-moz-transition-property:padding;-ms-transition-property:padding;-o-transition-property:padding;transition-property:padding;-webkit-transition-duration:.1s;-moz-transition-duration:.1s;-ms-transition-duration:.1s;-o-transition-duration:.1s;transition-duration:.1s;-webkit-transition-timing-function:ease;-moz-transition-timing-function:ease;-ms-transition-timing-function:ease;-o-transition-timing-function:ease;transition-timing-function:ease}.btn{color:#fff;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.18);background:rgba(0,0,0,0.38);text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08)}a.btn,a.btn:hover{color:white!important}.btn{margin-bottom:5px;color:#fff;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.18);background:rgba(0,0,0,0.38);text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08);-webkit-border-radius:2px;-moz-border-radius:2px;border-radius:2px}.btn:hover::after,.btn:focus::after{background:rgba(255,255,255,0.09);color:white}.btn:active::after{background:rgba(255,255,255,0.18) color:white}.btn_label.show{display:block}.btn::after{position:absolute;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;content:'';-webkit-border-radius:inherit;-moz-border-radius:inherit;border-radius:inherit}.btn.icon::before{display:block;content:'';position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;width:20px;border-radius:inherit;background:url('http://static.tumblr.com/tpqedpr/cQ1mbwb60/de.png') 0 0 no-repeat}.btn.theme::before{background-position:0 -0px}.btn img{width:15px}.btn.icon{padding-left:20px}.btn:active::after {background:rgba(255,255,255,0.18)}.clear {clear: both;} #pagination {display: all;}
</style>

<body>
 
 
 
<div id="sidebar">
<center>
<div id="blogtitle"><a href="/">{title}</a></div>
{block:IfShowsidebarpic}
<div id="sidebarpic">
<a href="/"><img src="{image:sidebar}" width=180px; border-radius=6px;><br><br>
</div>
{/block:IfShowsidebarpic}
</a>
{Description}<br><br>
<div id="desclinks"><center><select onchange='location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;' style='
line-height:90%;
font-size:10px;
text-transform:uppercase;
color:#000000;
width:180px;
background-color:white;
border:1px solid #eee;
height:18px;
font-family:consolas;
margin-top:3px;
padding:1px;
-moz-border-radius:3px;
-webkit-border-radius:3px;
border-radius:3px;
'>
<option>navigation</option>
 
<option value="{text:Link One}">{text:Link One Title}</option>
<option value="{text:Link Two}">{text:Link Two Title}</option>
<option value="{text:Link Three}">{text:Link Three Title}</option>
<option value="{text:Link Four}">{text:Link Four Title}</option>
</option></select></center>
</div>
</div>
</div>
 
 
<div id="content">
{block:Posts}
<div id="entry">
 
{block:Text}{block:Title}<span id="titletext">{Title}</span>{/block:Title}<span class="entrytext">{Body}</span>
<div class="permz"><center>{shortmonth} {dayofmonth}{dayofmonthsuffix} • <a href="{permalink}" target="_blank">{NoteCount} notes</a> • <a href="{ReblogURL}" target="_blank">reblog</a></center></div>
{/block:Text}

{block:Photo}
{block:IndexPage}
<div class="perms">
<div class="permstext">
<a href="{permalink}">{NoteCount}</a> • <a href="{ReblogURL}" target="_blank">reblog</a></div></div>
<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" width=260px/></a>{/block:IndexPage}{block:PermalinkPage}{LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"width=400px/>{/block:PermalinkPage}{block:ifshowcaption}{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{/block:ifshowcaption}{/block:Photo}

{block:Photoset}
{block:IndexPage}
<div class="perms">
<div class="permstext">
<a href="{permalink}">{NoteCount}</a> • <a href="{ReblogURL}" target="_blank">reblog</a></div>
</span>
</div>
<center>{Photoset-250}{/block:IndexPage}{block:PermalinkPage}{Photoset-400}{/block:PermalinkPage}{block:ifshowcaption}{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{/block:ifshowcaption}{/block:Photoset}
 
{block:Link}<a href="{URL}" id="titletext">{Name}</a>{block:Description}{Description}{/block:Description}
<div class="permz"><center>{shortmonth} {dayofmonth}{dayofmonthsuffix} • <a href="{permalink}" target="_blank">{NoteCount} notes</a> • <a href="{ReblogURL}" target="_blank">reblog</a></center></div>
{/block:Link}

{block:Quote}<center><span id="titletext">"{Quote}"</span><br><br>
{block:Source}<center><span id="bodytext">{Source}</span>{/block:Source}</center>
<div class="permz"><center>{shortmonth} {dayofmonth}{dayofmonthsuffix} • <a href="{permalink}" target="_blank">{NoteCount} notes</a> • <a href="{ReblogURL}" target="_blank">reblog</a></center></div>
{/block:Quote}
 
{block:Chat}{block:title}<span id="titletext"><center>{Title}</center></span>{/block:title}<hr><div class="chat">{block:Lines}<div class="chat"><div class="lux {Alt}"><div class="{Alt} user_{UserNumber}">
{block:Label}<span class="userlabel"><u>{Label}</u> </span>{/block:Label}{Line}</div></div></div>{/block:Lines}</div>
<div class="permz"><center><center>{shortmonth} {dayofmonth}{dayofmonthsuffix} • <a href="{permalink}" target="_blank">{NoteCount} notes</a> • <a href="{ReblogURL}" target="_blank">reblog</a></center></div>
{/block:Chat}

{block:Audio}
<div class="aart">{block:AlbumArt}<img src="{AlbumArtURL}">{/block:AlbumArt}</div>
<div class="aplayer">{AudioPlayer}</div>
<div class="audiotext">{block:Artist}<b>{Artist}</b>{/block:Artist}<br><br>{block:TrackName} "{TrackName}" {/block:TrackName}</br><br>{block:Album}<br> {Album} {/block:Album}</br>
{block:PlayCount}<b>{PlayCount} plays</b>{/block:PlayCount} • <b><a href="{permalink}" target="_blank">{NoteCount} notes</a></b></div>
{block:IndexPage}
<div style="margin-top:-10px; border-top:1px solid #ddd;"><center>
</div></center>{/block:IndexPage}
{/block:Audio}
 
{block:Video}
{block:IndexPage}
<div class="perms">
<div class="permstext">
<center>{shortmonth} {dayofmonth}{dayofmonthsuffix} • <a href="{permalink}">{NoteCount} notes • <a href="{ReblogURL}" target="_blank">reblog</a></center></a></div></div>
{/block:IndexPage}
 
<center>{Video-250}<BR></center>{block:ifshowcaption}{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{/block:ifshowcaption}{/block:Video}
 
{block:Answer}<div id="qstn"><div id="askr"><u>{Asker}</u></div><br><i>{Question}</i></div>
<center>{Answer}</center>
<div class="permz">
<a href="{permalink}">{notecount} notes</a>
</div>{/block:Answer}

 
{block:PermalinkPage}
<div id="permalinkpage">{block:caption}{caption}{/block:caption}<Br>{block:Date}{ShortMonth} {DayofMonth}{DayofMonthSuffix} {Year}{/block:Date}  · {block:NoteCount} {NoteCount} notes {/block:NoteCount}{block:HasTags} · tags: {block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}">#{Tag}</a>{/block:Tags}{/block:HasTags}</div>
{/block:PermalinkPage}
 
{block:PostNotes}{PostNotes}
{/block:PostNotes}</div>{/block:Posts}
</div></div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
<div id="dthemes">
    <div style="position:fixed;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    bottom:5px;
    right:5px;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    color:black;
    opacity:.9;">
    <a href="http://divisionthemes.tumblr.com/" target="_blank" title="division themes">师主题</a></div></div>
    
    <script language="JavaScript">
// FHS Tumblr follower counter and tracker
var height = '76';
var fhsf = document.createElement('script');
fhsf.src = "//tc.freehostedscripts.net/tcounter.php?url=iamyelled.com&name=Followers&a=1&s=1&h="+height+"";
document.head.appendChild(fhsf);document.write("<span id='f_counter'></span>");
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Is that how your html document structured ?

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa Yes.